# Do not allow extra properties with zod parse

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I'm using `zod` for validation. It seems like if I define a schema and then `parse()` some input with some extra properties that aren't even in the schema, `zod` parses the input as valid but just removes those keys.

```
import { z } from 'zod'

const schema = z.object({
  foo: z.string(),
  bar: z.number()      
})

// this validates fine, printing { foo: 'hello', bar: 1 }
console.log(schema.parse({ foo: 'hello', bar: 1, baz: true }))
```

However, extra input properties is not something I'd like to ignore, instead I'd like to throw a useful error when that happens, reporting the keys of the extra properties.

Is there a way to do that with `zod`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the [strict option:](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#strict)

```
const schema = z.object({
  foo: z.string(),
  bar: z.number()      
}).strict();
```

Comment: Ah great, thanks! Even throws an error with a code `unrecognized_keys` and an array of those keys.

Comment: It works, but how to make it as default? I don't want to pass .strict to every z.object.

Comment: Using `z.strictObject` instead of `z.object` solved my issue.

Comment: Note, `z.strict()` does not affect for nested objects.