# Zod validation schema that has 2 options

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, react-hook-form, zod

If i have a the following schemas, how can i create final schema so that i get the results when instanceB is invalid if parsed because it does not hold all values for SchemaB.

```
const SchemaA = z.object({
  propA: z.string({ required_error: REQUIRED }),
  propB: z.number({ required_error: REQUIRED }),
});

const SchemaB = z.object({
  propA: z.string({ required_error: REQUIRED }),
  propB: z.number({ required_error: REQUIRED }),
  propC: z.boolean({ required_error: REQUIRED }),
  propD: z.string({ required_error: REQUIRED }),
  propE: z.string({ required_error: REQUIRED }),
});

const FinalSchema = ...

const instanceA = { propA: 'valueA', propB: 42 };
const instanceB = { propA: 'valueA', propB: 42, propC: true };
const instanceC = { propA: 'valueA', propB: 42, propC: true, propD: 'test', propE: 'test' };

const resultA = FinalSchema.parse(instanceA); // Valid
const resultB = FinalSchema.parse(instanceB); // Invalid
const resultC = FinalSchema.parse(instanceC); // Valid
```

I was originally using `z.union([SchemaA, SchemaB])`

However instanceB is valid because it hold all values for SchemaA. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

add [strict function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70415330/do-not-allow-extra-properties-with-zod-parse) to the end of schemas (this is for throwing errors if there are extra fields in data). then you can use or function to combine two schemas. the code:

```
const SchemaA = z.object({
    propA: z.string({required_error: REQUIRED}),
    propB: z.number({required_error: REQUIRED}),
}).strict();

const SchemaB = z.object({
    propA: z.string({required_error: REQUIRED}),
    propB: z.number({required_error: REQUIRED}),
    propC: z.boolean({required_error: REQUIRED}),
    propD: z.string({required_error: REQUIRED}),
    propE: z.string({required_error: REQUIRED}),
}).strict();

const FinalSchema = SchemaB.or(SchemaA)

const instanceA = {propA: 'valueA', propB: 42};
const instanceB = {propA: 'valueA', propB: 42, propC: true};
const instanceC = {propA: 'valueA', propB: 42, propC: true, propD: 'test', propE: 'test'};

const resultA = FinalSchema.parse(instanceA); // Valid
const resultB = FinalSchema.parse(instanceB,{}); // Invalid
const resultC = FinalSchema.parse(instanceC);
```